# Custom UINavigationController UIToolbar Background Image

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I have an iPhone application using `UINavigationController` and would like to customize the elements with custom background images. I was able to do this for the `UINavigationController's` `UINavigationBar` pretty easily using Objective-C categories as below:

http://foobarpig.com/iphone/uinavigationbar-with-solid-color-or-image-background.html

I'd like to do the same for the `UINavigationController's` `UIToolbar`, but the same approach doesn't seem to work (although I have absolutely no idea why not.) I've looked around and people seem to suggest subclassing `UIToolbar`, but this isn't possible for the `UINavigationController's` toolbar, which is a read-only `UIToolbar`. I want to use the `UINavigationController's` toolbar instead of just making a subview toolbar because I'm using the slide-in `setToolbarHidden` animation.

Anyone have any idea if it's possible to apply a background image to this `UINavigationController` toolbar (most likely by somehow overriding the `drawRect` method)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to subclass instead of creating a category.

I'm not too sure why a category works for `UINavigationBar` but not `UIToolbar`, but subclassing works for both of them and I think it's the more standard way of customizing stuff like that.

So to subclass `UIToolbar`, create a class called `MyToolbar` (or something similar) and put this in the .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyToolbar : UIToolbar {}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect;

@end
```

And this in the the .m file:

```
#import "MyToolbar.h"

@implementation MyToolbar

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"my-awesome-toolbar-image.png"];
    [backgroundImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}

@end
```

From there you've got to tell the Navigation Controller to use `MyToolbar` instead of `UIToolbar`. Easiest way I've found to do that is to select your Navigation Controller in Interface Builder, then in the Attributes Inspector check the 'Shows Toolbar' box. The toolbar should show up in the `NavigationController` window. Click on it and then in the Identity Inspector change the class to `MyToolbar`.

Comment: Great! Thanks. Do you (or anyone else) know of a way to do the last step programmatically? I don't have my navigation controller set up with Interface Builder.

Comment: @Chris, I would also like to know how to override the toolbar programmatically. Thanks!

Comment: Asked/answered in another SO question since I needed to know: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15767291/1106878

Answer (score 10):

**Update:**

In iOS 5.0+ you now can use `UIAppearance` to customize the navigation bar.

---

Another way to do this is to simply create a Category for your application's `UINavigationBar` class.  This was pretty straightforward to implement:

**Interface:**

```
@interface UINavigationBar (TENavigationBar)

- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect;

@end
```

**Implementation:**

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (TENavigationBar)

- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation_background"];

    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 
                                 0, 
                                 self.frame.size.width, 
                                 self.frame.size.height)];
}

@end
```

Then this will be *globally* applied to all your `UINavigationBar`'s automatically.

Comment: Unfortunately this customizes the nav bar and NOT the toolbar.

Comment: Wow, good point.  I totally missed the mark on this one.  Still a good solution for nav bar though :)

Comment: I added two files to my code, UINavigationBar.h and UINavigationBar.m and added this code to them. I also tried with file names JHNavigationBar.h/.m. It wasn't automatically applied for me. What am I missing?

Comment: @joshholat are you running iOS 5.0+ only?  If so you need to use UIAppearance to customize.  This will only work on versions prior to 5.0.

Comment: @joshholat Did you include the interface file wherever it is used? Just adding the file to the project doesn't mean it will get used. Be sure to #import where you wish to use it.

Answer (score 2):

One of the best solutions is creating a category of UINavigationBar and UIToolbar. The next classes gives you a solution for iOS 4.0 and iOS 5.0 compatibility:

The only thing is you need to call the next methods in your viewDidLoad for example:

```
// Customizacion de navigation bar y toolbar compatible con iOS4 e iOS5
[UINavigationBar iOS5UINavigationBarBackgroundImage];
[UIToolbar iOS5UIToolbarBackgroundImage];
```

So, the class Category for iOS 4.0 and iOS 5.0 compatibility for customize BackgroundImage results like follow:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (BackgroundImage)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{    
    UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed: @"navigation-bg.png"];
    [img drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];  
    [self setTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x5ca666)];      
}
+ (void) iOS5UINavigationBarBackgroundImage
{
    if ([UINavigationBar respondsToSelector: @selector(appearance)])
    {
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"navigation-bg.png"] forBarMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x5ca666)];
    }
}
@end

@implementation UIToolbar (BackgroundImage)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"toolbar-bg.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    [self setTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x5ca666)];
}
+ (void) iOS5UIToolbarBackgroundImage
{
    if ([UIToolbar respondsToSelector: @selector(appearance)])
    {
        [[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"toolbar-bg.png"] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        [[UIToolbar appearance] setTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x5ca666)];
    }
}
@end
```

Greets!

Answer (score 0):

A simple option is to subclass UINavigationBar/UIToolbar and initialize the navigation controller using the method:

`- (instancetype)initWithNavigationBarClass:(Class)navigationBarClass toolbarClass:(Class)toolbarClass`

However, for simple customizations (as background images, shadows, etc.) I would recommend to use the `UIAppearance` protocol pattern.