# Custom UINavigationController UIToolbar subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, subclass, uitoolbar

I need to work with a subclassed `UIToolbar` in the `UINavigationController`. I know this can be done via `Interface Builder` but I need it to be done programatically.

The docs state that the `UINavigationController` toolbar property is readonly so I'm at a bit of a loss as to how I proceed.

Related:

- [Custom UINavigationController UIToolbar Background Image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3323636/1106878)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A new [init*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/initWithNavigationBarClass%3atoolbarClass%3a) method has been available since iOS 5

```
- (instancetype)initWithNavigationBarClass:(Class)navigationBarClass 
                              toolbarClass:(Class)toolbarClass
```

Also don't forget

> ... you are responsible for adding a root view controller before presenting the navigation controller onscreen.

Comment: Perfect, missed this. Thanks @Paul.s!

Comment: Where do I add this init method?

Comment: You need to create the navigationController using this method. So where ever you create your navigation controller use this instead.